# Prestashop 1.6 Webservice Order

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to finish my custom module to import clients, addresses, carts and orders from a webservice.

Clients, Adresses and Carts imports works fine but when trying to insert new Order, it returns this error:

```
This call to PrestaShop Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 500. That means: Internal Server Error.
```

If i take a look to my apache2 error.log I can see this error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function validateOrder() on boolean in /var/www/html/prestashop_pool/myshop/classes/order/Order.php on line 1463
```

This piece of code is the ones related to the order adittion via WebService:

```
// Getting the structure of an order
$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH .'api/orders/?schema=blank'));

    // Adding dinamic and required fields
    // Required
$xml->order->id_address_delivery    = $id_address; // Customer address
$xml->order->id_address_invoice     = $id_address;        
$xml->order->id_cart                = $id_cart; 
$xml->order->id_currency            = $id_currency;
$xml->order->id_lang                = $id_lang;
$xml->order->id_customer            = $id_customer; 
$xml->order->id_carrier             = $id_carrier;
$xml->order->module                 = $order_module;
$xml->order->payment                = $order_payment;        
$xml->order->total_paid             = $total_paid;
$xml->order->total_paid_real        = $total_paid_real;
$xml->order->total_products         = $total_products;
$xml->order->total_products_wt      = $total_products_wt;
$xml->order->conversion_rate        = 1;
// Others
$xml->order->valid                      = 1; 
$xml->order->current_state              = $id_status;        
$xml->order->total_discounts            = $total_discounts;
$xml->order->total_discounts_tax_incl   = $total_discounts_tax_incl;
$xml->order->total_discounts_tax_excl   = $total_discounts_tax_excl;
$xml->order->total_paid_tax_incl        = $total_paid_tax_incl;
$xml->order->total_paid_tax_excl        = $total_paid_tax_excl;
$xml->order->total_shipping             = $total_shipping;
$xml->order->total_shipping_tax_incl    = $total_shipping_tax_incl;
$xml->order->total_shipping_tax_excl    = $total_shipping_tax_excl;
// Order Row. Required
$xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[0]->product_id = $products[0]['id_product'];
$xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[0]->product_attribute_id   = $products[0]['id_product_attribute'];
$xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[0]->product_quantity       = $products[0]['quantity'];
// Order Row. Others
$xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[0]->product_name           = $products[0]['name'];
$xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[0]->product_reference      = $products[0]['reference'];
$xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[0]->product_price          = $products[0]['product_price'];
$xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[0]->unit_price_tax_incl    = $products[0]['product_price'];
$xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[0]->unit_price_tax_excl    = $products[0]['product_price'];

// Creating the order
$opt = array( 'resource' => 'orders' );
$opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$xml = $webService->add( $opt );
$id_order = $xml->order->id
```

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: are you using the correct $order_module? what version of prestashop 1.6 do you have?

Comment: My $order_module contains the name of my custom plugin to import( e.g:  'nameofplugin') and I'm using **Prestashop 1.6.0.14**. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I've tried to comment the line $order_module and the error changed to **This call to PrestaShop Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 400. That means: Bad Request.**

Comment: The name of $order_module is required and should be equal to the name of a payment module (for example 'bankwire' or 'cheque') , unless your module is a payment module.

Comment: My module is a ones to import orders (clients + addresses + carts + orders) from a webservice. If I set a name of order_module as 'cashondelivery' it charshes with the error mentioned on first post. (__PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function validateOrder() on boolean in /var/www/html/prestashop_pool/myshop/classes/order/Order.php on line 1463__)

Comment: have you tried dumping the vars ($this->module and $paymentModule) in that function after getting instance of module? `$paymentModule = Module::getInstanceByName($this->module);` doesn't return a Module class object and it's only returning true or false for some reason.

Comment: Mmmmm, I don't know ehere to dump but in adittion, I've set true _PS_MODE_DEV_ and now I've got more precission of my error. __HTTP XML response is not parsable: array ( 0 => LibXMLError::__set_state(array( 'level' => 3, 'code' => 4, 'column' => 1, 'message' => 'Start tag expected, \'<\' not found ', 'file' => '', 'line' => 1, )), )__

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139946/discussion-between-makros-and-sadlyblue).

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to the wrong values you are passing in

```
$xml->order->module = $order_module;
$xml->order->payment = $order_payment;
```

check this value, I think `prestashop` need `ps_ prefix` before adding module value.