# Prestashop 1.7.3 webservice - creating a new order -> 500 Error

Tags: php, api, e-commerce, prestashop-1.7

Clients, Adresses and Carts imports works fine but when trying to insert new Order, it returns this error:

```
This call to PrestaShop Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 500. That means: Internal Server Error.
```

I have the following code:

```
public function add_order(array $order, array $products)
    {                                    
        $xml = $this->webService->get(array('url' => $this->shop_path . '/api/orders?schema=blank'));

        $xml->order->id_customer = $order['id_customer'];
        $xml->order->id_address_delivery = $order['id_address_delivery'];
        $xml->order->id_address_invoice = $order['id_address_invoice'];
        $xml->order->id_cart = $order['id_cart'];  
        $xml->order->id_currency = $order['id_currency'];
        $xml->order->id_lang = $order['id_lang'];
        $xml->order->id_carrier = 1;
        $xml->order->current_state = 2;
        $xml->order->valid = 1;
        $xml->order->payment = 'Bankwire';
        $xml->order->module = 'bankwire';
        $xml->order->total_paid = $order['total_paid'];
        $xml->order->total_paid_tax_incl = $order['total_paid_tax_incl'];
        $xml->order->total_paid_tax_excl = $order['total_paid_tax_excl'];
        $xml->order->total_paid_real = $order["total_paid_tax_incl"];
        $xml->order->total_products = $order['total_products'];
        $xml->order->total_products_wt = $order['total_products_wt'];
        $xml->order->conversion_rate = 1.000000;

        foreach($products as $key => $product) {                                              
            $xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row->product_id = $product[$key]['id_product'];
            $xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row->product_attribute_id = 0;
            $xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row->product_quantity = $product[$key]['quantity'];
        }

        $opt = array('resource' => 'orders');
        $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
        $xml = $this->webService->add($opt);

        /*
        $order['id_order'] = $xml->order->id;
        $order['secure_key'] = $xml->order->secure_key;

        $xml = $this->webService->get(array('url' => $this->shop_path . '/api/order_histories?schema=blank'));
        $xml->order_history->id_order = $order['id_order'];
        $xml->order_history->id_order_state = '1';

        $opt = array('resource' => 'order_histories');
        $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
        $xml = $this->webService->add($opt);*/
    }
```

The xml sent is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<order>
    <id/>
    <id_address_delivery>483</id_address_delivery>
    <id_address_invoice>483</id_address_invoice>
    <id_cart>217</id_cart>
    <id_currency>1</id_currency>
    <id_lang>1</id_lang>
    <id_customer>195</id_customer>
    <id_carrier>1</id_carrier>
    <current_state>2</current_state>
    <module>bankwire</module>
    <invoice_number/>
    <invoice_date/>
    <delivery_number/>
    <delivery_date/>
    <valid>1</valid>
    <date_add/>
    <date_upd/>
    <shipping_number/>
    <id_shop_group/>
    <id_shop/>
    <secure_key/>
    <payment>Bankwire</payment>
    <recyclable/>
    <gift/>
    <gift_message/>
    <mobile_theme/>
    <total_discounts/>
    <total_discounts_tax_incl/>
    <total_discounts_tax_excl/>
    <total_paid>27.8</total_paid>
    <total_paid_tax_incl>27.8</total_paid_tax_incl>
    <total_paid_tax_excl>23.36</total_paid_tax_excl>
    <total_paid_real>27.8</total_paid_real>
    <total_products>27.8</total_products>
    <total_products_wt>27.8</total_products_wt>
    <total_shipping/>
    <total_shipping_tax_incl/>
    <total_shipping_tax_excl/>
    <carrier_tax_rate/>
    <total_wrapping/>
    <total_wrapping_tax_incl/>
    <total_wrapping_tax_excl/>
    <round_mode/>
    <round_type/>
    <conversion_rate>1</conversion_rate>
    <reference/>
<associations>
<order_rows>
    <order_row>
    <id/>
    <product_id>19</product_id>
    <product_attribute_id>0</product_attribute_id>
    <product_quantity>2</product_quantity>
    <product_name/>
    <product_reference/>
    <product_ean13/>
    <product_isbn/>
    <product_upc/>
    <product_price/>
    <unit_price_tax_incl/>
    <unit_price_tax_excl/>
    </order_row>
</order_rows>
</associations>
</order>
</prestashop>
```

I am using PSWebServiceLibrary.php and I have debug modus turned on. But the error message is way too generic for me.

I have searched stackoverflow and the prestashop forums. Others have the same problem (for example: [Prestashop 1.6 Webservice Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202517/prestashop-1-6-webservice-order)).

But it seems nobody knows what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking into this, make sure:

- You have a customer and an address for that customer
- Your cart has id_carrier as well as id_address_delivery and id_address_invoice
- Your order must have these fields filled (others are not required):

  - id_address_delivery, id_address_invoice
  - id_cart
  - id_customer
  - id_currency
  - id_lang
  - id_shop
  - id_carrier
  - conversion_rate
  - module
  - payment
  - total_paid
  - total_paid_real
  - total_products
  - total_products_wt
  - total_shipping
- Your XML looks like this:

  ```
  <prestashop>
    <order>
      fields mentioned above...
    </order>
  </prestashop>
  ```

To see what values the fields require you can go to `yourSite.com/api/orders/1?&ws_key=yourKey`